# Why do the relations $ab=1/2$ and $a>b$ imply $a^2>1/2>b^2$ for positive $a,b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

When I was reading a probstat book, I encountered an example which I am able to understand except for a formula which I am not able to grasp. It may be basic but I am not able to get it, the solution goes like this:

We have $0 < a < 1$ , $0 < b < 1$  , $a b = \frac{1}{2}$ , $a > b$

Then the author wrote $a^2 > \frac{1}{2} > b^2$

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
a>b
$$
therefore
$$
a^2>ab>b^2
$$

and we have 
$$
ab = \dfrac{1}{2}
$$

To complete.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a>b$, one has $a^2 = aa >ab = \frac{1}{2}$. Similarly $b^2 = bb < ab =\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Of course $a > b$ implies $a^2 > b^2$ because $a$ and $b$ are both positive.

To get $a^2 > \frac 12$, start from $ab = \frac 12$. Then because $a > b$, $aa > ab = \frac 12$. Similarly, $a > b$ implies $ab > bb$.